# rotate an image inside a layer or the layer itself with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, image, rotation, kineticjs

I have one stage with dimensions 800x600 initialized like this

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    width:800,
    height:600,
    container:'container'
});
```

then I initialize one backgroundLayer like this

```
backgroundLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    width:800,
    height:600,
    visible:true,
    draggable:true,

});
```

and an Image object like this

```
imageObj = new Image()
image.src = "../path/to/image/"
imageObj.onload = function (){
    backgroundImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image:imageObj,
        width:800,
        height:600,
        offset: {x: 400, y:300}
    });
    backgroundLayer.add(backgroundImage);
}
```

and  I am adding image to backgroundLayer and layer to stage

```
stage.add(backgroundLayer);
```

Having the offset setup like this makes the image appear only in the upper corner of the stage and have to drag it to see it. What also happens that if I rotate an image the previous one is still there (unrotated) until I drag it. So my question:

1. Is it better to rotate Image or Layer?
2. Where should offset be and why is it causing this kind of error in showing image and layer
3. How can I make that image dissappear from behind?
4. If I drag image or layer(according to what I have set up as draggable) outside the boundaries of my canvas, do I have to do any calculations before rotating or does KIneticJs do it automatically?

As always thanks in advance!

EDIT: The image dissappears from behind if I do stage.draw() and not call the draw() method on the layer or the image. For the others I still don't have a clue.